# jQuery Succinctly syntax explanation

Tags: jquery, syntax

I just downloaded the jQuery Succinctly free ebook ([here](http://syncfusion.com/jquerybook)) from Syncfusion and started looking through the examples.

I see a lot of this type of thing:

```
<script> (function ($)
{
    $('a').mouseenter(
        function () { alert(this.id); });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I'm not sure why the author is using this syntax.  The `$` object is being passed into the anonymous function?  Why?  And what is the `(jQuery)` following the anonymous function for?

Is this simply a way to avoid conflicts with other libraries?  It seems to me these examples could be written much more "succinctly" :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It creates a closure where `$ === jQuery` even if `$.noConflict()` was used to remove the global jQuery `$`.

That allows you to always use `$` without having to care if the user is e.g. also using a framework such as prototype which also uses `$`.

The closure also has the advantage that your variables/functions are not global unless you explicitely make them global (by not using `var` and attaching functions to the `window` or `this` object)

Comment: Just a few seconds ahead of me. :/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a succinct way to avoid jQuery conflict with other libraries. It's known as a "closure". In other words, the variable `$` is scoped to that function and can be used without harm outside of it.